# Erro: .toLowerCase() is not function No Pipe search Ionic3

Tags: ionic, algoritmo-de-busca, pipe

Boa tarde, criei um pipe para pesquisar, porém está dando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search',
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
  transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!terms) return items;
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter( it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
    });
  }
}
```

O que poderia ser ?

Comment: Verifica se realmente o 'terms' é uma string, pois vc pode estar passando um number sem saber. Pra garantir, faça assim: terms.toString().toLowerCase();

Comment: Boa noite Gesiel, tentei dessa forma, e apareceu outro erro "Cannot ready property "toLowerCase" of undefined, sendo que coloquei um console.log no terms e ele está assumindo o valor digitado.

Comment: Tenta usar um "isString(terms)" para verificar se realmente é uma string.

Comment: Já consegui, coloquei um Json.stringfy e resolveu, Obrigado! mais tarde posto a solução certinha aqui.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo a variável terms esta sendo definido onde?? 
o problema é esse coloca

terms = 'meutermsquevemdealgumlugar';

define tua variável que vai dar certo.

Comment: Já foi resolvido brother, problema era de conversão, utilizei o Json.Stringfy e deu tudo certo. Abraço.

Comment: De fato era o parse para o string